# error: cannot find module nativescript-angular/router or its corresponding type declarations

Tags: angular, nativescript

Reading the native script documentation and watching videos I want to use `RouterExtensions` but I get the following error:

```
cannot find module nativescript-angular/router or its corresponding type declarations
```

My code

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";
    
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    
  constructor( private page: Page,private routerExtensions: RouterExtensions) {
    
    page.actionBarHidden = true;
              
  }
    
  onAccess(){
    //log here
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

[image: Screen error]

Comment: Can you post the package-json and angular.cli.

Answer (score 8):

Change:
import { RouterExtensions } from "nativescript-angular/router";

Into:
import { RouterExtensions } from "@nativescript/angular/router";

In newer versions of nativescript/angular projects.

Kind Regards